# 15.4" Retina MacBook Pro (Mid 2012): Broken metal pieces from connector on the motherboard

Tags: macbook-pro, display, repair

Yesterday I was replacing the housing on my 15.4" Retina MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) (A1398). When I was removing the Logic-board, I broke this little metal parts from one connector. I don't actually know what is that connector for (MagSafe 2 charging port maybe?). Is it important? Is that maybe grounding/earthing? Should I be worried about that and fix it?

MacBook is Working normally but it seems to me that it has some static electrical charge right now. I was reading little bit about that - and it says on forums that electrical charge may appear once the laptop is disassembled.

[image: Broken little metal parts from motherboard]

Answer (score 1):

If it is the connector for the part you have circled in red in the left picture on the bottom row, that is a microphone assembly, containing two microphones. So if i understand you correctly in that the connector where the flat cable contact for this assembly slides into, on the motherboard, partially broke, you will now probably not get any mic input registered on your Mac, although I am uncertain if this model also has a mic in the lid next to the camera.

Comment: Thanks for you reply guys. Yes, correct. It is connector of the microphone. I will try if microphone works. I'm not sure it has microphone in the lid next to the camera - at least i can't see any hole over there.

Comment: But i can also feel electrical charge now on my laptop ( alloy housing ). What may be the reason for that? Because i didn't use gloves for static electricity when i was working

Answer (score 0):

They look like the [pins from the SD Card Reader](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295933/119271); you can see the solder on the ends of the joint.  However, without close inspection it's  impossible to know for sure, but they look pretty close.

Are they important?  Yes.  Especially so if you intend to use the SD Card reader.  What's more important is that they are falling out!

Also, much like a car, it’s critical to diagnose the failure after finding bits of metal inside the critical areas.  Small bits of metal indicate not just a failure but can cause catastrophic damage to the whole.

Comment: No, these are not pins fromthe SD Card Reader. It's from the microphone.